# 3rd person camera gimble lock

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation

This camera controller does exactly what I need, the only issue is there are limits for rotating beyond looking straight up and straight down. When the camera limits are removed and it rotates beyond 90 up or down, the camera flips. This is due to gimble lock, correct? Is it possible to rewrite this to allow for full continuous rotation around the object? I have experimented with another controller that utilizes RotateAround(), but I prefer how this controller feels - if it can be rewritten, that would be best.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform _player;

    public Transform player 
    {
        set { _player = value; }
        get { return _player; }
    }

    public Vector3 cameraOffset;

    private float minXRotAngle = -85F;
    private float maxXRotAngle  = 85F;

    private float rotX;
    private float rotY;

    public float mouseRotateSpeed = 3.3333F;

    public float swivelSlerp = 0.1f; 
    private Quaternion cameraSwivel;

    private Vector3 smoothDampVelocity;
    private float smoothDampSpeed = 0.05F;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;

        cameraOffset = new Vector3(0, 0, -50);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Rotate();
    }

    void Rotate()
    {
        rotX += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseRotateSpeed; // around X
        rotY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseRotateSpeed;

        if (rotX < minXRotAngle)
            rotX = minXRotAngle;
        else 
        if (rotX > maxXRotAngle)
            rotX = maxXRotAngle;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Quaternion cameraSwivelTarget = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0);
        cameraSwivel = Quaternion.Slerp(cameraSwivel, cameraSwivelTarget, swivelSlerp);

        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, player.position + cameraSwivel * cameraOffset, ref smoothDampVelocity, smoothDampSpeed);

        transform.LookAt(player.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This strange rotation occurs because the camera rotates when the angle between two objects is 0 or 180 degrees. Main reason is the way quaternions interpolate rotation.
If you need rotation on full 360 degree only for one side then it should be something like that:

```
Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position;
direction.y = 0; //rotation only around Y-axis
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
```

If you need to rotate around both the x and y axes, then you need to change the code to rotate each axis independently.
I suggest you explore this [example](https://github.com/EmmaPrats/Camera-Rotation-Tutorial). In my humble opinion this is the easiest way to do it.